# Using Angular2's Reactive Forms, is it possible to bind to a radio's name attribute?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a component that wraps a set of radio inputs that use the same `formControl`, but without a name attribute the browser tab order is not correct.  So I'm trying to bind to name like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'direct-radio-group',
  `<label *ngFor='let option of options'>
      <input type="radio" [name]='name' [formControl]='control' [value]='option[0]'>
      <span>{{ option[1] }}</span>
    </label>`
})
export class DirectRadioGroup {
    @Input() name: string;
    @Input() options: [string, string][]
    @Input() control: FormControl; 
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work; the browser still treats radios in two different instances of the component as the same tab stop.

I also tried using `[attr.name]`:

```
<input type="radio" [attr.name]='name' [formControl]='control' [value]='option[0]'>
```

Which does allow you to tab appropriately, but when using the same set of options the browser will change the value of all radio groups instead of just the one that is changed.

Here is a Plunker demoing this behavior: https://embed.plnkr.co/uVquX9ZnOqlI8rd8w6bz/

What's the right way to accomplish this?

**Update**
Binding to both `[attr.name]` and `[name]` produces the expected behavior.  Discussion here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11757